# Unity: Cannot register type from different assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to implement `Dependency injection` in my MVC application. I'm using `Unity.Mvc3.dll` for IoC. I just wondering how the Unity can't register Types from another assembly. Here's the code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    var container = new UnityContainer();

    // ok: register type from this assembly
    container.RegisterType<IMessages, Messages>();

    // fail: register type from another assembly (service reference)
    container.RegisterType<IPlayerService, PlayerService>();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
}

public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this._container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in the MVC Controller:

```
[Dependency]
public IPlayerService PlayerService { get; set; }

[Dependency]
public IMessages Messages { get; set; }


public ActionResult Index()
{
    PlayerMessageViewModel vm = new PlayerMessageViewModel();
    vm.Messages = Messages; // success!
    vm.Players = PlayerService.Get(); // fail: null reference exception :PlayerService

    return View(vm);
}
```

`PlayerService` is always null while the Messages is OK.

Here is the `PlayerService` Class

```
public class PlayerService : IPlayerService
{
    private readonly MyDbEntities _dbContext;

    public PlayerService()
    {
        _dbContext = new MyDbEntities();
    }

    public PlayerService(MyDbEntities dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }


    public IQueryable<Player> Get()
    {
        return _dbContext.Players.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

this is the complete Error Message

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>   Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default unity picks the constructor with the most parameters, so I think it'll be trying to use the second constructor with the dbContext parameter, which it can't resolve.  If you mark your default constructor with the attribute [InjectionConstructor] then hopefully that will solve your problem

Comment: what library InjectionConstructor attribute is included?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionconstructorattribute(v=pandp.20).aspx

Comment: still no luck, I even removed the overloaded ctor but to no avail

Comment: I don't think that there's no work around with this one, How come other's implemented it with WCF services types.

Comment: Hmm, not sure then, I guess you're going to have to implement the suggestions made by others to try and get a more meaningful message out about the type that is failing to resolve

Comment: got it, it's infact the constructor which has the error, MyDbEntities(EF) is the one that has an error in config, I just confused because it doesnt throw the error related to the EF. I ll mark this as an answer for the InjectionContructor attribute that actually solve the problem with two ctor. THANKS MUCH!

Answer (score 7):

You are hiding all exceptions with `catch { return null; }` try to remove it and see what exception is thrown while resolving. I think exception is thrown in `PlayerService` constructor.

**EDIT:**

From http://mvchosting.asphostcentral.com/post/ASPNET-MVC-3-Hosting-Problem-in-implementing-IControllerActivator-in-ASPNET-MVC-3.aspx

> When an MVC application starts for the first time, the dependency
> resolver is called with the following types in the following order:
>
> - IControllerFactory
> - IControllerActivator
> - HomeController
>
> If you did not implement your resolver to return null if a type is not
> registered then you will probably end up seeing an error similar to:
>
> The current type, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, is an interface
> and cannot be constructed

Comment: it should hit the default ctor right? I cant get the debugger go to the breakpoint in ctor.

Comment: Yep, `public PlayerService()`

Comment: I remove the null and replace throw exception and this is what i get  `the current type, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?`

Comment: Is there something wrong in the Player Service? I dont think it's in the MyDbEntities which is an Entity Framework edmx

Comment: can't get where IControllerFactory dependency is required

Comment: I also found that link, but cant understand it really, do I need to Implement also the IControllerFactory? and where do I put it in my code.. I am really newbie in MVC let alone unity.. SMH..

Comment: the error is misleading, but thanks for the input, youre the first to give the hint that the error is in the PlayerService constructor which is right. But I'd give it to Fergus for the InjectionConstrutor attribute. It's a shame that the error message is very misleading.

Answer (score 2):

You are violating the contract of `IDependencyResolver`. It should return `null` for types which can not be resolved. The problem with Unity is that it tries to build all classes that it can find, no matter if they are registered in the container or not.

Hence a class somewhere can not be built.

There is also a `Unity.Mvc3` package available in nuget.

Comment: it's actually originally returns null but I just replace throe exception to see the actual error as suggested by the other poster.

Comment: Your `throw` hides the problem that you got from the start since `IControllerActivator` is invoked before any controller is invoked. Change back to return null and LOG all exceptions (or put a break point in the catch block)

Comment: reverted it, and breakpointed it in the catch: here is the inner exception: `The current type, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?`

Comment: btw infact, Im actually using Unity.Mvc3 from Nuget

Comment: Continue to to return `null` for all ASP.NET/MVC3 classes until the controller is invoked. It's that exception we are interested in.

Comment: thanks dude, got it by drilling trial in error, it should infact return null, the Ctor of the PlayerService the one that causing the error. Thanks!

Comment: I helped you find the answer, but you accepted another answer? `Hence a class somewhere can not be built`

Comment: it's a shame I cannot pick two answers, but I felt that Fergus answer is the one that helped me more, plus he added the InjectionConstructor which is also a part of the error because PlayerService has multiple constructor. I would have not get it if I did not put the attribute in the default Ctor. An upvote is all I can give.

Answer (score 0):

The current type, **(EX-DI.IBLL.IEmployee)**, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

**Ans -** Just in `Unity.config.cs` add the following thye

```
public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            // register all your components with the container here
            // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

            **container.RegisterType<IEmployee,EmployeeManager>();**
//this could be your interface and the class implementing the interface.

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        }
    }
```